# iPad TV guide app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I have to develop an **iPad TV guide** that looks like
[What's On TV](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/whats-on-tv-from-zap2it/id289190113?mt=8).

I tried to do it using a UITableView with many row as the number of channels. In order to create a kind of grid, I added a subview for each row that contains all the programs (UIButton with different size). In order to scroll the view horizontally I added gesture recognizer and change the UIView (subview cell) position every time I swipe right or left.

That works, but the solution seems to me a bit messy and the animation is not so reactive. Do you have any idea (or example) for a better solution? What about html5?

Thanks

My code:

in ViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

   _chName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
   _chName.text=((Channel *)[_resultEPGChannel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).name;

   _viewCell = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
   _viewCell.frame=CGRectMake(-_positionView, 0,2000, 77);

  //add the view to the _viewCell (moving view) with the right program for each channel (row)
  cp = [[ChannelProgram alloc] init] ;
  cp.allProgram=[_resultEPGProgram objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  [_viewCell addSubview:cp];

  return cell;}
```

In ChannelProgram.m (subclass of UIView)

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

    int xPoint=2;

    for (Program *singleProgram in allProgram) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

        [button setTitle:singleProgram.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(xPoint,0, singleProgram.lengthProgram,75);
        [self addSubview:button];
        xPoint = xPoint+singleProgram.lengthProgram+2;}
```

The animation it's very slow, and become worst every time I had to reload the table. What's wrong?

Comment: Run the program through a profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event drawRect is own draw, every time redraw you will create new UIButton, so you may get a lot of UIButton far more than you need.

UIButton is a control, you can just add it to ChannelProgram at `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` or `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`, this will not cause any memory waste.

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I used initWithFrame and works like a charm!